# Specific value of one quadrant python

Tags: python, cartesian, cartesian-coordinates

I would like to know how could I get the total value of the first quadrant:

```
aa = { (0, 1) : 4, (2, 2) : 6, (3, 1) : 7, (1, 2) : 10, (3, 2) : 11,(0, -5) : 4, (-2, -2) : 6, (-3, 1) : 7, (1, -2) : 10, (-3, 2) : 11 }

values = aa.values()

total = sum(values)


for (x,y) in aa:
    
if (x>0 & y>0):

 print(total)
else :
 pass
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `sum` method with a conditional on the x and y coordinates.

```
aa = {(0, 1): 4, (2, 2): 6, (3, 1): 7, (1, 2): 10, (3, 2): 11, (0, -5): 4, (-2, -2): 6, (-3, 1): 7, (1, -2): 10,
      (-3, 2): 11}


total = sum(aa[(x,y)] for x,y in aa if x >= 0 and y >= 0)
print(total) # prints 38
```

Comment: Yes, I updated to include >= 0 to for x and y. Before, it was just > 0.

Comment: Correct me if im wrong but if I want to put it under a function would that be :                         def intensites(aa):

  aa = { (0, 1) : 4, (2, 2) : 6, (3, 1) : 7, (1, 2) : 10, (3, 2) : 11,(0, -5) : 4, (-2, -2) : 6, (-3, 1) : 7, (1, -2) : 10, (-3, 2) : 11 }




  total = sum(aa[(x,y)] for x,y in aa if x>=0 and y >= 0)
  print(total) # prints 34

(intensites([]))